# App in background

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, multitasking

I have an iPhone 5C, running an app that is connected to a Bluetooth device. When the connection to the Bluetooth device is lost (spreading apart, Bluetooth turned off etc.) the app sounds a buzzer. From what I´ve read, specific apps are allowed to run in the background, and some of them communicate with Bluetooth devices. For this particular app, that is true almost all the time.

The problem happens when I browse in the Web. Sometimes the app gets killed and the buzzer sounds. I am sure it gets killed because when I tap on the app in the multi-tasking UI, it reopens. When I tap on the app while running, it shows the Bluetooth device connected. Is there a way to prevent the app from getting killed?

The App is Itrack Easy and the device is a Bluetooth button. I am testing this App because I intend to use this device as a panic button connected to the phone with my own App. My problem is not that hear the buzzer or not. My problem is that if this test App gets killed, mine will too and the button will not work as a panic device, available when the phone is near.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Kindly edit the question to include relevant information to help with the answer. Information like the name of the app and why you do not wish to hear the buzzer sound when browsing the Web will help in getting relevant answers. For instance, from your problem statement, it appears that the app is programmed to make the user aware of the lost connection to the Bluetooth accessory.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't force iOS to keep an app active in the background.  In fact, Apple specifically instructs iOS developers to assume their app will be removed from memory soon after the user puts it into the background.

The app developer would need to code the app in such a way that it handles disconnections from the bluetooth device in a graceful way (assuming the buzzing you hear when the app goes into the background is **not** an intended function).  The developer can also add code to allow the app to periodically 'wake up' and check for the bluetooth connection.  However, there's nothing you can do from your side on that.

I recommend you contact the app developer and see if they've already addressed this in a new app version (your iPhone 5C can't run iOS 11 or newer).  If not, do they intend to fix it or do they offer a work-around.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. My iPhone is running iOS 112.6. Apple states that Apps that connect with bluetooth devices are allowed to run in the background. This specific App can run in the background, but also gets killed unexpectedly when I browse in the web. I need to know why that happens, contradicting Apples's statements

Comment: I am doing this research in order to develop my own App to use this device. The present App does work in the background almost always. Is it that browsing in the web makes the phone run out of memory and iOS kill the App. Wouldn´t that contradict the principle of connecting with Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Are you sure you have an iPhone 5C?  The maximum iOS version allowed is [10.x](https://everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html).  Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: Apps can run in the background but they don't stay active there.  They can be removed with the OS needs the memory (like for web browsing).  They sleep and then are woken-up according to [how the developer coded it to interact with the OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html), BTLE for example.

Comment: I checked my iPhone and you are right, it is 5S, not 5C  Model is A1457. It is actually running iOS 11.3.1, just updated

Comment: You might be able to contact the developer to see if they have an update or a beta that fixes the problem you're experiencing.